# I want to display a FB comment box on every page but have their own comments specific to that page

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I recently coded my own blog for a site im making. I want to use facebook to handle the comment on posts, so i integrated the plugin. I noticed something odd however. If i comment on one blog post, then go to a different one, my comment is on the other blog posts as well. How do i make it so each post has its own set of comments?

Answer (score 4):

You have to set a different data-href attribute for each post. Here's an example of how I do it in Yii:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://domain.com/post/view/<? echo $model->id; ?>" data-num-posts="4" data-width="695"></div>
```

The point is the data-href value has to be unique for each post.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using html5 comments box.

**Refer to:** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

`data-href=""`  // data href sets the url "object id" for the box, you need to use a dynamic system with php, or javascript or what ever language you coded in.

---

```
<div style="padding-left:5px; min-height:500px" class="fb-comments" data-href="'+newUrl+'" data-num-posts="20" data-width="380"></div>
```

---

"i use"  **EXAMPLE:**
the following examples works for pages with dynamic urls

```
example.com?id=thisid&thisarticle=article-name
```

---

```
<div id="thecomments"></div>
    <script>
    function changeCommentsUrl(newUrl){
    // should refresh fb comments plugin for the "newUrl" variable
    document.getElementById('thecomments').innerHTML='';
    parser=document.getElementById('thecomments');
    parser.innerHTML='<div style="padding-left:5px; min-height:500px" class="fb-comments" data-href="'+newUrl+'" data-num-posts="20" data-width="380"></div>';
    FB.XFBML.parse(parser);
    }
    var thisurl = document.write(document.URL);
    changeCommentsUrl(thisurl);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply place that kind of snippet in your footer :

```
<script>
    $(".fb-comments").attr("data-href", window.location.href);
</script>
```

It does the job...

Comment: +1! Nice trick. Although bear in mind that appending the *data-href* value has to be done *before* calling the facebook script. Just pointing out because in the documentation it is loaded just after the *<body>* tag when there is no *data-href* value.